# How to solve "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, python-3.7, object-detection, imageai

I am not having the error but when I run the below line its continuously showing that kernel
appears to dead. It will restart automatically.

I am having the python 3.7.10 and tensorflow 2.4.0 installed.

The error is showing when I run the below line of code.

```
from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer
```

I tried every solution which is mentioned on google but unable to solve.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6haFo.png)

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Have you tired importing this in Python run from command line? What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

There could be the problem with supported package version mismatch in the anaconda environment. You can try by restarting the kernel after sometime or can rectify this error by creating a new environment and install the `TensorFlow`  and other required packages again on that.

Create a new environment for `TensorFlow` using the code below:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

and insatll `TensorFlow`:

```
conda install pip
pip install tensorflow
```

You need to open the `JUPYTER notebook` in the same environment by selecting the `"tf2"` and try importing `TensorFlow` :

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

if there is no error - `TensorFlow` installed successfully.

Now, you can install any reuired package using `!pip install package_name` in `Jupyter Notebook`, as in this case:

```
!pip install imageai
```

Also check this link as a reference for using [imageai](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customdetection/)